# Php & mysql if table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have this section of cod:

how i can stop this section

```
for($i=0; $i<$n-1 ; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO text (ID, TXT) 
        VALUES ('$id', '$sir[$i]')");
            $id++;         
}
```

if table isn't empty ?

Answer (score 3):

Do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM text
```

and check how many entries you have. If cnt>0 place a break at the beginning of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add before the specific block:

```
// count the rows
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(ID) as numrows FROM text");
// fetch the result
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
// check if count = 0
if($data['numrows'] == 0) {
    // execute the codeblock
    for($i=0; $i<$n-1 ; $i++) {
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO text (ID, TXT) 
        VALUES ('$id', '$sir[$i]')");
            $id++;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about insert if table is empty as below?

```
INSERT INTO my_table (colname)
SELECT 'foo'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a select a row and see what happens...

```
if (!($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID FROM text LIMIT 1")) || $result->num_rows < 1) {
    if($result) {
        $result->close();
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO text (ID, TXT)
            VALUES ('$id', '$sir[$i]')");
        $id++;
    }
}
```